# PreparedStatement setBigDecimal from params

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, bigdecimal

I have DAO with save method

```
public void save(BigDecimal cashBackAmount){
 try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
             stmt.setBigDecimal(1, cashBackAmount);
             stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

and findbug says:

```
FindBugs: Unchecked/unconfirmed cast This cast is unchecked, and not all instances of the type casted from can be cast to the type it is being cast to. Check that your program logic ensures that this cast will not fa
```

How can I setBigDecimal?

```
stmt.setBigDecimal(1, new BigDecimal(????));
```

Comment: Are you sure that the warning is for that line? There's no casting going on whatsoever. You get a BigDecimal argument and provide it to a method taking a BigDecimal argument.

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore the warning/error. The message is completely meaningless in this case.

It is clear that you are already receiving `BigDecimal`. So there is no possibility that you receive some other object.